# Cannot launch app after installing AppsFlyerLib

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the AppsFlyer SDK into my SwiftUI iOS app. I've installed the framework via cocoapods.

But now when running the app (My Mac, Designed for iPhone), I get this error:

> The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of macOS.
> Failed to verify code signature of /var/db/appinstalld/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.rxLc7F/extracted/panicdiary.app/Frameworks/AppsFlyerLib.framework : 0xe8008029 (The code signature version is no longer supported.)

I also get a different error telling me: 'Unable to install" when trying to run on my iOS device.

How can I remedy this?

Comment: Remove the pod. Apple is doing a lot of cleanup right now likely in preparation of the intel phaseout starting in June. Hopefully AppsFlyer has a newer version you can install.

Comment: Try looking for an SPM version on their site